# How to prevent rerendering of children inside List component of react-window

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, react-usememo, react-window, react-memo

### Problem

I'm trying to achieve a behaviour, when merely changed items of the list are being updated and rerendered with new data.

I wrote a component which is being updated when timer is off:

```
import { FixedSizeList as List } from 'react-window';


function ProfilesList() {
   ...

   // Here is an effect which fetches new data every time and component is rerendered with new data

   React.useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            dispatch(loadProfilesList());
        }, intervalTime);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timer);
        };
    }, [dispatch]);

    ...

    return (
       <List height={758} width={625} itemSize={82} itemCount={filteredProfiles.length}>
            {({ index, style }: { index: number; style: any }): React.ReactElement => {
                return (
                    <div style={style} key={index}>
                        <Tooltip title={t`stop` as string}>
                            <Button>lalla</Button>
                        </Tooltip>
                    </div>
                );
            }}
        </List>
    );
```

And as a result, when timer is off, all items are rerendered, but none of them wasn't changed practically, which is resulting in flickering appearance of a tooltip:

[image: flickering tooltip]

### Some investigation

I checked `react-window` `FixedSizeList` (which is used for `List`) render method. And here is some questions which I didn't answer myself yet:

- Why list itself is rerendered if all props are the same? Seems like this isn't optimized, so the component will be rerendered at any case, won't it? ([render method sources](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window/blob/b0a470cc264e9100afcaa1b78ed59d88f7914ad4/src/createListComponent.js#L290))
- And looking into render method, how `props.children` are used, `List` component uses `React.createElement` to create a new element from passed-in `props.children`. So I started to think that it's possible to memoize children and came up with this change to return result from function component:

```
    const memoizedChild = React.useMemo(() => {
        const memo = ({ index, style }: { index: number; style: any }): React.ReactElement => {
            return (
                <div style={style} key={index}>
                    <Tooltip title={t`stop` as string}>
                        <Button>lalla</Button>
                    </Tooltip>
                </div>
            );
        };
        memo.displayName = 'memo';
        return memo;
    }, []);

    return (
        <List height={758} width={625} itemSize={82} itemCount={filteredProfiles.length}>
            {memoizedChild}
        </List>
    );
```

And it looks like `React.createElement` doesn't give a damn about memoized children component and therefore React mounts it over and over again. So I stumbled upon this, wondering if it's `React.createElement` to blame or user code (my code) is written badly.

### Questions

- Is it possible to resolve this tooltip flickering appearance issue with user code changes? What should be changed?

These will be also helpful to have answered:

- If previous answer is no, then, what changes should be made inside `react-window`?
- And this one especial curious, does `React.createElement` handles properly memoized `type` argument, according to its definition:

```
React.createElement(
  type, <- If this one is memoized, I mean
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to resolve this tooltip flickering appearance issue with user code changes? What should be changed?

All is pretty straight. When I was passing a function as a child, it was constantly being created over and over again. So the solution was to move child function definition out of render method like so:

```
const MyButton: React.FC<{ style: any; index: number }> = ({ index, style }) => {
    return (
        <div style={style} key={index}>
            <Tooltip title={t`stop` as string}>
                <Button>lalla</Button>
            </Tooltip>
        </div>
    );
};
```

and use it in render method like so:

```
<List height={758} width={625} itemSize={82} itemCount={filteredProfiles.length}>
    {MyButton}
</List>
```

> And this one especial curious, does React.createElement handles properly memoized type argument, according to its definition ...

`createElement` doesn't handle memoization, it simply creates a react element. Memoization itself assures that the component will be not created if nothing changed.